# Can MySQLdb Connection and Cursor objects be safely used from with multiple threads?

Tags: python, thread-safety, mysql-python

I'm using mysqlclient v1.3.10 in Python 3.5. After connecting to the database, you get a connection object, from which you get a cursor object that you use to run your queries.

Are these objects thread safe (i.e. can I create one set and then share and use them between multiple different python threads)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that you can't. The [MySQLdb documentation](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html#mysqldb) states (scroll down a little further to **threadsafety**):

> The general upshot of this is: Don’t share connections between
>   threads. It’s really not worth your effort or mine, and in the end,
>   will probably hurt performance, since the MySQL server runs a separate
>   thread for each connection. You can certainly do things like cache
>   connections in a pool, and give those connections to one thread at a
>   time. If you let two threads use a connection simultaneously, the
>   MySQL client library will probably upchuck and die. You have been
>   warned.