# What happens when multiple threads are writing to a single table in mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading

I am facing a situation where multiple threads are trying to insert data to the same table in mysql, **Will it be OK without explicit handle it? ** I am afraid every thread is inserting, some thread will be locked and hold on too long, then cause the program to corrupt.

Basically I am trying to do is the following:

```
import threading
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect()
cursor = db.cursor()


def update_to_table(data):
    sql = "insert into my_db.my_table values(%s)" % data
    cursor.excute(sql)
    db.commit()
    print("update complete!")


for i in range(10):
    print("%d -th time..." % i)
    data = get_data(i)
    t = threading.Thread(target=update_to_table, args=(data,))
    t.start()
```

Do I need to check if other threads are inserting, and hold on and waiting until them to finish etc...

The data for different i has no overlap so we don't need to worry about the duplicate key problem.

**After experimenting, it seems some thread will hang on and no response.**

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that suggests your threads are "holding on too long." And how do you propose to check other threads that you have no control of? Tell us more about the result of your experimenting as to what you discovered about "it seems some thread will hang on and no response." Have you tried not sharing the connection and cursor objects between threads, that is having each thread acquiring its own instances?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45636492/can-mysqldb-connection-and-cursor-objects-be-safely-used-from-with-multiple-thre

Comment: @RonaldAaronson I use the same `db` and `cursor` across different threads(as shown in my code), is that a preferred way to do?

Comment: No, the preferred way is to create a "connection pool" of N connections that can be shared among threads. N may be fewer than the number of concurrent threads, in which case a thread may be waiting for a connection to become available. But the point of my previous comment is that it may be actually illegal to share a connection between threads the way you are doing if a connection is not "thread safe" and it can give rise to problems including the one you say you are having. For now, try moving the assignment to **db** and **cursor** in to **update_to_table** and see if that helps.

Comment: Take a look at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html

Comment: @RonaldAaronson what do you mean by: "the preferred way is to create a "connection pool" of N connections that can be shared among threads", if I move `db` and `cursor` to `update_to_table`, I think now each thread has its own connection, is that what you mean by a "connection pool"?

Comment: No., that's not a connection pool. Did you bother following the link I posted? Doing what I suggested to solve your problem gives each thread a dedicated connection. If you have a program that creates many, many threads throughout the day it can be expensive to create and free database connections. A connection pool will pre-allocate N connections that are reusable among all the threads that will be created. As long as you never have more than N threads running concurrently, no thread will ever have to wait to acquire a connection.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson Thanks for the brief explanation, I got your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MySQL Connector/Python Developer Guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysql-connector-threadsafety.html), the `mysql.connector.threadsafety` property is `1`.

According to [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), the meaning of the `threadsafety` property is as follows:

> 0 - Threads may not share the module.
>
> 1 - Threads may share the module, but not connections.
>
> 2 - Threads may share the module and connections.
>
> 3 - Threads may share the module, connections and cursors.
>
> Sharing in the above context means that two threads may use a resource without wrapping it using a mutex semaphore to implement resource locking. Note that you cannot always make external resources thread safe by managing access using a mutex: the resource may rely on global variables or other external sources that are beyond your control.

In your example, you have threads sharing a single connection. without any explicit resource locking.   That is liable to lead to threading problems, and the symptoms you observe (threads locking up) are not unexpected.

The simple solution in this example is to give each thread its own connection object.

(If the thread count was large, you would be advised to use a connection pool with a bound on the number of concurrent connection.  The DB server will limit the number of connections that one client can have open ... to husband server-side resources.  Furthermore, there will be a point at which you are using all of a particular server-side resource; e.g. CPU, memory, disk bandwidth, network bandwidth.  Beyond that point, adding more client threads won't increase throughput.)

Comment: Do you suggest that I should move db and cursor inside update_to_table, so that everything is alright?

Comment: Yes, the assignment to these variables should occur inside update_to_table as the first two statements.